# DateTimeFormatter 2018-06-18 20:07:08.908193+00

Tags: java, datetime-format

I am attempting to deserialize a DateTime object with jackson. The value stored in object is `2018-06-18 20:07:08.908193+00`. The section after the period (`.908193`) is what I can't quite figure out, anyone have any thoughts?

I tried below pattern but it doesn't seems to work.

```
 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn+xx")
```

Comment: Your format pattern has a `:` instead of a `.` separating seconds from nanoseconds, is this the problem or is this simply a typo?

Comment: @Vulcan Pattern also have `+xx` in the end. This should also give error. It should be replaced with `X` based on the input given by filer

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, see answer below!

Comment: then accept his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues with your input and pattern

1) Your input have `.` after seconds section but your pattern have `:` in it, try replacing it

2) Your pattern have +xx in the end. I should be `X`

`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnX");`

Comment: Thanks that is the correct answer, I was just ignoring the timezone in the one I was using above.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn+00");
```

Comment: Adding `+00` instead of the proper zone offset code here will ignore that part of the datetime if there is ever anything other than the zero offset timezone.